# Is there any special graph to stand for the Interface in argoUML tool?

Tags: uml, argouml

I use the argoUML tool to analyses the class architecture .

It's easy to find the graph to stand for the Class or Package . But I can't find a special graph to stand for Interface.

Is the graph which standing for the Class for Interface ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had found the graph of the Interface . There are a number of different between class and interface.

New class [image]

New interface [image]